# Units of Hamming, and Euclidean distance

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

This is just a simple doubt I wanted to clear. I'm calculating the Hamming and Euclidean distance between two columns in a matrix, where each column is storing time information in seconds of when a particular event occurred. When I calculate the Hamming and Euclidean distance between the two columns, I get back a certain value. What is the units of measure for that value? Is it in seconds?

Comment: I propose the *Hamming* to be the unit!

Answer (score 2):

The Euclidean distance has the same units as the positions are measured in.  The Hamming distance has no units.  Think of changing units, say from meters to centimeters.  The numeric value of the Euclidean distance will multiply by 100, but the Hamming distance will not change.